# "Meet" or "meet to" or "meet with"

Tags: grammar, sentence-choice

1. I meet my friend every day.
2. I meet to my friend every day.
3. I meet with my friend every day.

Is "meet" a transitive, or intransitive, or both?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show you have done some research on this. Thank you.

Comment: In not sure, from what is written, why you wouldn't understand the answer from references, including free online resources.

Comment: I am voting not to close for three reasons. First, I am not totally content with the reference given by Fumble Fingers. Second, The distinction between "meet" and "meet with" in American usage **is** subtle enough that a learner may not have the research tools to address it. Third, I prefer to tell a new user how to improve a question rather than discourage questions by closing them. In this case, the way to improve the question is to indicate what research the quetioner has already done and what is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In U.S. English, "meet" means "encounter." It sometimes means "encounter for the first time."

> I met my brother by accident in O'Hare Airport last week.
>
> I met my wife in grade school.

The first does not imply that I never met my brother until last week.

The second does not imply that my wife and I were married while in grade school.

"Meet with a person" usually means "to talk with a person, usually for a purpose."

> I met with my boss on the new project.